# Undo app updates?

Tags: updates, uninstallation

How to undo app updates? I was on terraria while it was updating, after that I lost my character and my world! It says the save file of my character was created with a newer version and could not be loaded, help!

Comment: Duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34757/is-there-a-simple-way-to-undo-an-app-update?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Nerd explanation: Look for the APK of the old version on a site like [Apkmirror.com](http://apkmirror.com)

If you didn't understand that here's the long version.

1. Go to settings->security and check "Allow installation from unknown sources"
2. Go to settings->apps->terraria
3. Look for the version and write it down/remember it
4. Go to [Apkmirror.com](http://apkmirror.com) and search for the app.
5. Download the file with the version number below the one you wrote down.
6. press on the confirmed download and click install

Note: This will only work with free apps.

**Disclaimer: Installing APK files from the internet can be dangerous. Only install APKs from reputable sites.**